# Jackson API Produces a JSON but cannot consume same JSON

Tags: json, web-services, rest, jackson, jersey-client

I am trying to implement a RESTful Web Service with Jackson and Jersey Servlets. My Webservices can produce this particular JSON as shown

```
{  
   "email":"aditya@123.com",
   "source":{  
      "G":33.2470567,
      "K":-95.89996559999997
   },
   "destination":{  
      "G":33.0198431,
      "K":-96.69888559999998
   },
   "waypoints":[  
      {  
         "location":"Dallas, TX, USA",
         "stopover":true
      },
      {  
         "location":"Houston, TX, USA",
         "stopover":true
      }
   ]
}
```

But when I try to consume the Same JSON it gives an internal server 500 error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('Â' (code 194)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

My POJOs & web service is as shown:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class RiderVO {
    private String email;
    private MapLocation source;
    private MapLocation destination;
    private List<Waypoint> waypoints;
    //getters and setters
    }

@XmlRootElement
public class MapLocation {
  private Double G;
  private Double K;
  //getters and setters
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Waypoint {
   private String location;
   private Boolean stopover;
   //getters & setters
}
```

WEB SERVICE:

```
 @POST
    @Path("/saveAll")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String saveRideJson(RiderVO riderVO){
        //do something
    }
```

I cannot figure out when it can produce a particular JSON why cannot I consume it. I did try changing the boolean parameters, and check if its isVar setter issues like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316321/true-or-false-into-boolean-using-jackson-json-parsing). But even that did not fix. Any suggestions are helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably, you have a different quote character in your json. Try deleting all the quote characters and retype manually.

Comment: WELL, That fixes it! It is probably because I had the habit of copying the JSON directly from the Online JSON formatter. And this usually seems alright, but when I typed the whole JSON string once again, it worked. Thanks a lot!